# how to insert audio file in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

I want to insert recorded audio file into sqlite DB from iphone,Not file path of audio file.
data Type is blob in  my table.i m getting error in below line:
NSData * vc=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[recordedTmpFile path] options: 0 error:nil];
recordedTempFile is recorded audio file(NSURL),
How do i insert NSData as blob type in sqlite...
Give me proper guidelines...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to tell what's going on from the ill-formatted one line code sample you've provided above. Please provide some more surrounding data.

Irrespective of all that, why on earth do you want to store audio data in a database? (Just store the file in your app's storage area and a reference to the file's path, any associated data you want to search on, etc. in the database.)

Comment: i can store file in documents folder but this is to be inserted in sqlite(likes images) but how?we do images in Nsdata using blob data type in sqlite like this how do i store audio data in sqlite.

Comment: As I've said, you should store audio and image files in the documents folder and just references to the files in the database.

Comment: thanks for u r reply.as u told, i should save referenece file path to be saved in the database? correct me if m i wrong..